# Images showing as Transparent when copied from another project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

From one project I went to the local folder that images were there, copied them and came to my project and pasted the images in my project.
In the original project they look like this with that image icon:
[image]

But in my project that I copied them too, they look like this:

[image]

Is that the reason the image is showing as trasnapert in my page? or maybe CSS issues?

Comment: The issue was I did not have bootstrap-theme.css in my project, once added that, it started looking better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon means they aren't included in your project file.

Right click them and click Include in Project.